# When did the custom of silver candlesticks for Shabbat start?

Tags: minhag, history, wedding, provenance, candle-lighting

I heard that it is a custom to give a bride candlesticks. Is this true? when did this start? Who has the obligation to do this? and more info on the subject with sources please.

Is this true that it is good to respect the mitzvah of Shabbat candles and do it on silver candlesticks?

Comment: This seems to be two very different questions.

Comment: I know people who use glass candlesticks. I think they thought they were prettier.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am one of them

Comment: It's most likely for the same reason that many people have a silver kiddush cup (or another metal).

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

Is this true that it is good to respect the mitzvah of Shabbat candles and do it on silver candlesticks?

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קלט - הלכות חנכה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0138_L2) writes, regarding the Menora that it's best to have a metal menora, as opposed to a clay one which cannot be reused from one night to the next.

He then goes on to say that if one can afford it, it's best to get a silver one, as this beautifies the Mitzva:

> וְעַל כֵּן תִּהְיֶה לוֹ מְנוֹרָה נָאָה שֶׁל מִינֵי מַתֶּכֶת. וּמִי שֶׁיָדוֹ מַשֶּׂגֶת, יִקְנֶה מְנוֹרָה שֶׁל כֶּסֶף לְהִדּוּר מִצְוָה‏

So we see that silver utensils are considered as a way to respect a Mitzva and are commendable.

As to your first question, I don't know, but the Be'er heitev in [סימן תרעג שמנים ופתילות הכשרות לחנכה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0138_L2) mentions that the [Maharshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria) (16th century) used a silver Menora.

> באר היטב  (יג) חרס. רש''ל קנה של כסף ובליל ב' התחיל להדליק בה ובירך להדליק ושעשה נסים ושהחיינו אף שבשעת קנין יש לברך מכל מקום ניחא לסדר ברכות שהחיינו עם אלו שני ברכות מט''מ. ובסדה''י האריך שכל א' יטריח לעשות לו מנורה יפה ומי שידו משגת יעשה של כסף וכן הנרות יעשה יפה:‏